# What SSD interface/form factor is compatible with my 13" MBP (Mid 2012)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I have an old MacBook Pro (13", Mid 2012; 5,400 RPM HDD) that I want to bring back to life with an SSD.

The options I've been exploring are the 2.5" SATA SSDs—am I looking for the right component? I just realized there's mSATA, not sure if that's what I should be looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! A 2.5 inch SATA SSD like [this one from Samsung](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OBRFFAS) or [this one from Crucial](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IAGSDUE) or [this one from Western Digital](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LXPENRR) will work.
(Note that those three are just examples.)

Comment: You'll also want to grab a T6 screwdriver since you'll need one to open the drive caddy.

Comment: I personally recommend the Samsung one Noah linked to. I've had the EVO 850 for 2 years and the only issue I had was actually Apple's fault

Comment: @Rajiv: That was my first choice, but sadly it's CAD$50 more expensive than the 525 GB Crucial (also linked).